# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync gets incomplete content

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, downloadfileasync

I'm using `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` to obtain a batch of files. However some files turn out to be incomplete, and there is no exception.

My question is, how to flag when a downloaded file is not complete? There is no md5 checksum to verify.

Code snippet is:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    Uri sUri = new Uri(sFileLink);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(sUri, myPath);
}
```

Comment: Try to download the file using `client.DownloadFile`. Will it be downloaded completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're disposing of the client before it's finished downloading. Don't do that.

You should only dispose of the `WebClient` when either there's an error or it's completed, which you'd discover by the events that `WebClient` raises (or using `DownloadFileTaskAsync` in .NET 4.5, and awaiting the resulting task).